# How to compile a kernel with other application?

Tags: compilation, kernel

I need to build a kernel with some default apps installed in it.

For example, when someone will install this kernel the default apps/packages will be installed with the kernel.

For example:
1. PHP support.
2. Apache server.
3. Python, perl
4. some other libraries etc.

Comment: Applications and libraries are not the part of the kernel and installing them is usually **distro-specific**. So you need to configure your distro so it will have given applications pre-installed.

Comment: thanks, I don't have any idea except simple kernel compilation. is there any example   that how to put applications/libraries pre-install while compiling kernel?

Comment: Again, the **kernel** does **not** include **applications** / **libraries**. So the question `how to put applications/libraries pre-install while compiling kernel?` has no more sence than `how to put *Python* pre-install while compiling *Perl*?` Applications (even system ones) are part of the Operating System (OS), but "OS" is not an equivalent to "kernel". Instead, OS *contains* kernel, applications and many other things. I would suggest you to read some articles (e.g. wiki) about what OS is.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142188/how-to-include-a-user-level-c-program-in-linux-source-to-be-compiled-with-the-li/58142359#58142359